# What R packages are available for nonparametric regression of two predictors?

Tags: regression, nonparametric, smoothing

I would like to fit a nonparametric regression model with two predictors.
What R packages are available?
I found 'loess' function in 'stats' package and 'gam' function in 'gam' package.
Is there anything else?

Comment: Depending on what you mean by non-parametric, boosted regression using the gbm package might help.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy. What I would like to do is basically to compare multiple methods; so I need as many methods as possible. Please recommend anything if you know something.

Comment: If you want something a bit "exotic" you might try multivariate adaptive regression splines as those are available in the package `earth`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is far from comprehensive, but you should also take a look at `locfit` for various "local" methods and `wavethresh` for wavelet methods. John Fox's [list](http://socserv.socsci.mcmaster.ca/jfox/Courses/Oxford-2005/R-nonparametric-regression.html) of packages from 2005 should be helpful (though is bound to be somewhat outdated).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I just tried 'locfit' and it works well. But I don't know which function to use in 'wavethresh'. Could you give me a very simple example? (In case of 'locfit', it would be locfit(Y~X1+X2,data=data.sample) )

Comment: I don't know wavelet methods so well so I'll just point you to Schafer and Wasserman's [tutorial](http://astrostatistics.psu.edu/samsi06/tutorials/tut2larryl_all.pdf) on nonparametric inference (example using 'wavethresh' starts on pg. 92). You can get the WMAP data from the example at [Wasserman's website](http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~larry/all-of-statistics). Hope that helps!